# Cannot convert value of type 'FirstViewController' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

```
SegueUtils.sendDataPrepareSegue(segueName: "first", dVC: FirstViewController)

//function defination of segue utils
class func sendDataPrepareSegue(segueName: String, dVC: UIViewController)
{
// calling prepare for segue here, is it the correct way of doing that if no, show me the path
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the instance of type `UIViewController`

Comment: What is exactly your requirement?

Comment: What is exactly your _question_? There's no there there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass instance of FirstViewController .

```
let objFirst : FirstViewController // change as per your needs
SegueUtils.sendDataPrepareSegue(segueName: "first", dVC: objFirst)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
let vcFirst : FirstViewController!
SegueUtils.sendDataPrepareSegue(segueName: "first", dVC: vcFirst)
```

Comment: Check the new answer.